# Redirect url on tab change

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am using ASP AjaxControlToolkit tabs. My problem is whenever user change tab, url should change according to the respective tab.

Here is my code:

```html
<asp:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="100%">
    <asp:TabPanel ID="TabPanel1" runat="server">
        <HeaderTemplate>Tab1</HeaderTemplate>
        <ContentTemplate></ContentTemplate>
        <asp:TabPanel ID="TabPanel1" runat="server">
            <HeaderTemplate>Tab2</HeaderTemplate>
            <ContentTemplate></ContentTemplate>
            <asp:TabPanel ID="TabPanel1" runat="server">
                <HeaderTemplate>Tab3</HeaderTemplate>
                <ContentTemplate></ContentTemplate>
```

For Example - If user selects:

- `Tab1` - Url should be /WebForm1.aspx
- `Tab2` - Url should be /WebForm2.aspx
- `Tab3` - Url should be /WebForm3.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way , redirect the page by using `OnActiveTabChanged` event .

Html code

```
<asp:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" AutoPostBack="true"
        OnActiveTabChanged="tbMain_ActiveTabChanged" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="100%">
```

server side

```
protected void tbMain_ActiveTabChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (TabContainer1.ActiveTabIndex == 1)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/WebForm1.aspx")
        }

        if (TabContainer1.ActiveTabIndex == 2)
        {
           Response.Redirect("~/WebForm2.aspx")
        }                
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Support.ExceptionHandler.HandleException(ex);
    }
  }
```